# React final form change function doesn't work correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-final-form, final-form, react-final-form-arrays

I'm trying to play around with React-Final-Form library, Here is my sandbox link : https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-vaughan-czk7g9?file=/src/index.js

When I click on 'Change' button, I want the country field (coming from the initialValues) to be get set or its value should get changed to the new given value. But what's happening is, country's existing value gets picked up and a new object key-value pair with key as "country's existing value" and value as the new value given gets appended.

Could someone helps what's wrong I'm doing here and how could I change the value of the field via change function.

Thanks.

Comment: If i understand correct, you want to change property `country` manually. You can do it like this `form.change("person.country", "France");`

Comment: @Vitaliy Rayets Thanks a lot. Could you help me how to do this if we want to change more values via looping. This is another sandbox code: https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-violet-g6oi4o?file=/src/Form.js I'm trying to update all values on click of a button, but this one too is just appending new values rather than changing the existing one.

Thanks again.

Comment: Object.values(values[0].forEach((field,index)=>form.change(`person[${index}].employed`, true));